# Move SVN Repository to Another SVN Repo as Sub-Directories

Tags: svn, repository

I have 3 svn repos on a linux machine as

```
Main Project
  -trunk
  -branches
  -tags

Project A
  -trunk
  -branches
  -tags

Project B
  -trunk
  -branches
  -tags
```

What I want is a directory structure as following ....

```
Main Project
  -trunk
  -branches
  -tags
  -Sub-Projects
    -Project A
      -trunk
      -branches
      -tags
    -Project B
      -trunk
      -branches
      -tags
```

Can anyone help me out on which is the best way...

Also the Projects are as `/conf /db /hooks /locks format readme.txt`

**Update:** I created the sub directories using `svn mkdir`. Now they are showing up correctly as `Main Project/Sub-Projects/Project` A. Now how can I move the contents from Project A repo to the new location and also maintain history. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subversion externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) is the best answer (with some limitations and precautions, yes) without physical transferring of repositories

I.e

- You save all three independent repos
- in Repo for `Main Project` you'll create `Sub-Projects` dir
- In Sub-Projects root you'll create two externals definitions for roots of Project A and Project B and have three physical repo but one united logical tree

[Playground-repo for externals](https://www.assembla.com/code/subversion-troubleshoot-b/subversion/nodes) on Assembla, open for reading and public: see current state, inspect short history

Comment: I created the sub directories using `svn mkdir`. Now they are showing up correctly as `Main Project/Sub-Projects/Project A`.
Now how can I move the contents from Project A repo to the new location and also maintain history. Please help.

Comment: I am new to this can you help me out with some command line examples using details from my question. It will be of great help.